# Bootstrap/AngularJs : How to set bold attribute for the active selection of nav class?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to set **bold** attribute on the active selection of the nav bar item. How do i acheive this?

```
 <ul class="nav">
       <li role="presentation" ng-repeate="item in items" 
          ng-class="{'active':navLink == item.header}">
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Not bootstrap specific but you could use the [active](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp) CSS selector for items in your header.

Comment: @joemillervi i have updated my question.

Comment: @ joemillervi,  i don't want to use css selectors since i don't want my anchor  active style gets affected globally. I want this style change locally only for this nav list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to research how to target specific elements with CSS selectors. This is neither HTML,Javascriupt nor Angular related - this is purely CSS and style rule specificity.

You use CSS and set the style rule for the active selection:
(assuming the active selection is called activeLink... and your nav ul has an id of navList. Note that I also have navLink in the li classes as well - which could also have been used to target the correct elements.

**#navList .activeLink{font-weight:bold}**

using a nav ul from W3 for demonstration - when you set the activeLink on the li - it will cause that to display bold.

```
 <ul id="navList">
  <li class="activeLink"><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

You then need logic in the page to change the active link for each page. I use php and set the active page before I call the nav into the page and then have an if statement in the li that echoes the class in if it is the active page.

```
    <?php $activePage="home";?>

    // other code
 <ul id="navList">
  <li class="navLink <?php if($activePage=="home"){echo"activeLink";}?>"><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li class="navLink <?php if($activePage=="news"){echo"activeLink";}?>" ><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li class="navLink <?php if($activePage=="contact"){echo"activeLink";}?>"><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="navLink <?php if($activePage=="about"){echo"activeLink";}?>"><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you need to learn about CSS and selector specificity - I have amended my answer to include an id for the nav menu - when you use CSS stylerules to target that then the global styles will not be altered - only the links within the nav menu that match the CSS selectors.